# Interpreting OLS Weights after PCA (in Python)

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, pca

I want to interpret the regression model weights in a model where the input data has been pre-processed with **PCA**. In reality, I have 100s of input dimensions which are highly correlated, so I know that PCA is useful. However, for the sake of illustration I will use the **Iris** dataset.

The **sklearn** code below illustrates my question:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets, sklearn.decomposition
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# load data
X = sklearn.datasets.load_iris().data
w = np.array([0.3, 10, -0.1, -0.01])
Y = np.dot(X, w)

# set number of components to keep from PCA
n_components = 4

# reconstruct w
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)
w_hat = reg.coef_
print(w_hat)

# apply PCA
pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components=n_components)
pca.fit(X)
X_trans = pca.transform(X)

# reconstruct w
reg_trans = LinearRegression().fit(X_trans, Y)
w_trans_hat = np.dot(reg_trans.coef_, pca.components_)
print(w_trans_hat)
```

Running this code, one can see that the weights are reproduced fine.

However, if I set the number of components to 3 (i.e. `n_components = 3`) then then weights printed out deviate substantially from the true ones.

Am I misunderstanding how I can transform back these weights? Or is it because of PCA's information loss moving from 4 to 3 components?

Answer (score 1):

I think this was working fine, it's just that I was looking at the `w_trans_hat` instead of the reconstructed `Y`:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets, sklearn.decomposition
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# load data
X = sklearn.datasets.load_iris().data
# create fake loadings
w = np.array([0.3, 10, -0.1, -0.01])
# centre X
X = np.subtract(X, np.mean(X, 0))
# calculate Y
Y = np.dot(X, w)

# set number of components to keep from PCA
n_components = 3

# reconstruct w using linear regression
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)
w_hat = reg.coef_
print(w_hat)

# apply PCA
pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components=n_components)
pca.fit(X)
X_trans = pca.transform(X)

# regress Y on principal components
reg_trans = LinearRegression().fit(X_trans, Y)
# reconstruct Y using regressed weights and transformed X
Y_trans = np.dot(X_trans, reg_trans.coef_)
# show MSE to original Y
print(np.mean((Y - Y_trans) ** 2))

# show w implied by reduced model in original space
w_trans_hat = np.dot(reg_trans.coef_, pca.components_)
print(w_trans_hat)
```